# Bootstrap Jumbotron Class Not Rendering Grey Highlight

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning to code, and my Jumbotron class in Bootstrap isn't rendering the grey highlight at all. Can someone please take a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<div class="Jumbotron">
  <h1>This is a Jumbotron</h1>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet pastrami shankle jerky tail, ground round hamburger sausage spare ribs strip steak burgdoggen pancetta</p>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Hi there!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `jumbotron` it's lowercase. Try `<div class="jumbotron"> </div>` .

Comment: That was IT! Thank you so much ZombieChowder!